# Java/P5: How to declare an Array of Arraylists holding FloatLists?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, processing

If I can declare an Array of FloatLists: `FloatList [][] values = new FloatList[3][3];`

Why doesn’t it work to declare an Array of ArrayLists holding FloatLists like this: `ArrayList<FloatList> [][] values = new ArrayList<FloatList>() [3][3];`? OR EVEN: `ArrayList<FloatList> [][] values = new ArrayList<FloatList> [3][3]();`

How can this be achieved? Will it be hard to refer to the `floats` buried deep under its crusty texture?

Comment: `ArrayList<FloatList> [][] values = new ArrayList[3][3];` However, conceptually, this starts becoming excessively complicated.

Comment: I have a 2D matrix and within each of the squares is an unknown quantity of categories. Within the categories a series of values is held. When the matrix is complete, the median values for each of the categories is found and displayed.

Comment: Updated it with more fleshy text. Basically, you're instantiating an array of something, and not a bunch of somethings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList<FloatList> [][] values = new ArrayList[3][3];
```

Basically, you're declaring that you want an object that is a 3D array of `ArrayList`s, and not generating actual `ArrayList` objects.

Afterwards, you have to instantiate each of them, so for example:

```
values[0][0] = new ArrayList<>();
```

And so on.

Answer (score 2):

Work from the inner-most type to the outer-most type. You start with `FloatList`:

```
FloatList
```

Then wrap that in an `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<FloatList>
```

Then you want an array of that:

```
ArrayList<FloatList>[]
```

Or a 2D array:

```
ArrayList<FloatList>[][]
```

That gives you the type for the declaration, but then you have to initialize the variable by giving it a value. Start with the array by giving it a size:

```
ArrayList<FloatList>[] array = new ArrayList[10];
```

This gives you an array of `ArrayList<FloatList>` objects, but they start out as `null`. To give them a value, you'd loop over every index in the array and use the `new` keyword to set the value of the index to an instance of `ArrayList<FloatList>`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   array[i] = new ArrayList<FloatList>();
}
```

For a 2D array, you'd use the same logic, just in a nested `for` loop.

Then to add a `FloatList` to an `ArrayList` at a specific index of the array, you'd do this:

```
array[i].add(new FloatList());
```

Finally, to add a `float` to a `FloatList` in an `ArrayList` at an index in the array, you'd do this:

```
array[x].get(y).append(0.5);
```

And to get a `float` out of an index in the `FloatList` in an `ArrayList` at an index in the array, you'd do this:

```
float f = array[x].get(y).get(z);
```

Putting it all together, it looks like this:

```
ArrayList<FloatList>[] array = new ArrayList[10];

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   array[i] = new ArrayList<FloatList>();
}

array[1].add(new FloatList());

array[1].get(0).append(0.25);
array[1].get(0).append(0.5);
array[1].get(0).append(0.75);

float f = array[1].get(0).get(2);

println(f);
```

Comment: `ArrayList<FloatList>[] array = new ArrayList[10];` this code generate `Unchecked Warning`. Is there any way to remove it without `SuppressWarning("unchecked")`

Comment: @seal Please note that this is a Processing question, and Processing does not generate any warnings for this code.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because of the way the JVM provides Generics. Generics in Java is a front-end compiler feature that becomes raw type usages and casts at execution time.

**What is the compiler doing when I use generics?**

Here's a terribly-contrived example. Let's say I want to create a `List<String>` to store command line arguments that I will later use to kick off a new process with, like so:

```
List<String> cmd = new ArrayList<>();
cmd.add("java");
cmd.add("-jar");
cmd.add("path/to/my.jar");
...
String args = cmd.get(0)+" "+cmd.get(1)+" "+cmd.get(2);
```

At compile time, the compiler will check to make sure that I am using the `String` type every time I use a generic `List` method via `cmd` and throw an error if I try to use instances of an incompatible type.  However, there's a little thing called **erasure** that happens during compilation, before execution.  Effectively, under the hood, the compiler converts the code above into something like this:

```
List cmd = new ArrayList();
cmd.add("java");
cmd.add("-jar");
cmd.add("path/to/my.jar");
...
String args = (String)cmd.get(0)+" "+(String)cmd.get(1)+" "+(String)cmd.get(2);
```

**So why doesn't my generic array code compile?**

In your example, you wanted to create an array of a generic type, like so:

```
ArrayList<FloatList>[][] array = new ArrayList<FloatList>[n][m]; //Doesn't compile? What gives?
```

The problem is, because of type erasure, the `ArrayList<FloatList>` class type doesn't really exist, and now you've asked the JVM to create a 2-dimensional array of that non-existent type.

**Okay, so what's the alternative?**

Well ... it isn't pretty, but you could do something like this:

```
class ArrayListOfFloatList extends ArrayList<FloatList>{
    ...
}

//Somewhere else in your code:
ArrayListOfFloatList[][] myArray = new ArrayListOfFloatList[n][m];
//This will compile because ArrayListOfFloatList is a real class.
```

The only other way around this would be to not use arrays.  Ugly, perhaps, but it's unfortunately a limitation of how Java is currently implemented.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. The code you're saying doesn't compile, compiles just fine.

Comment: Your edited code doesn't compile because `LinkedList` is not a subclass of `ArrayList`, not because of generics. You absolutely do **not** have to use a generic subclass in order to user generics with arrays.

Comment: Fair point. I still don't think extending `ArrayList` is a very reasonable solution (especially in the Processing context), but downvote retracted.

Comment: I totally agree, which is why I said it wasn't pretty :)  But you also don't want to get into the habit of ignoring compiler warnings. I guess it's up to the OP to choose his poison wisely ;)

Comment: Another thing worth considering is that this is Processing, not standard Java, so a lot of your syntax wouldn't make sense to a Processing developer. But it looks like OP is long gone, so I'll digress. Thanks for the back and forth!

Comment: Ahhhhh, I didn't know that "Processing" was a thing, I just figured it was another tag like "algorithms" - learn something new every day :)